Display 'Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.' after I run the PySimpleGUI example
I installed PySimpleGUI according to the official documentation (using the 'python3 -m pip install pysimplegui') command. And I tried to run the official example:
Example
It shows：
dingkwanmok@DingkwanMacBook-Air PyBus % /usr/bin/python3 /Users/dingkwanmok/Desktop/test/PyBus/main.py
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00000001f8d83ac0 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1381 in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1414 in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 925 in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1058 in _handle_fromlist
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 704 in __gPwEtwj_from_global_variable
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 681 in __gPwEtwj
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 86 in __GiKHei
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 735 in __NhS6p
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 220 in __wAbkBSp
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1039 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  File "obf_Cleaned_PySimpleGUI50_source.py", line 1049 in __ArWOcDX
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 17472 in StartupTK
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10214 in _Show
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10481 in _read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10403 in read
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21740 in _error_popup_with_code
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 21699 in _error_popup_with_traceback
  File "/Users/dingkwanmok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16557 in PackFormIntoFrame
  ...
zsh: abort      /usr/bin/python3 /Users/dingkwanmok/Desktop/test/PyBus/main.py

My Environment：MacBook Air M2; macOS Sonoma 14.4.1; Python 3.9.6; VS Code 1.88.0
I tried reinstalling the PySimpleGUI library.

What detail version of your tkinter ? You may check it by import tkinter as tk;tk.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel'). It may happened when there's no PhotoImage class under your tkinter. Try to install another Python from https://www.python.org/.

I think it should be a problem with the python that comes with macOS. I tried installing Miniconda python and it work fine.
